# Google analyzing URL

Tags: seo, google, url, keywords, top-level-domains

We all know Google analyzes URLs in order to get relevance. That's why JavaScriptoptimizer.com hits the first place for the "javascript optimizer" query.

These are my questions:

1. Does Google differentiate between keyword.com and keyword.info?
2. Also does a .info website get less points?

Comment: That's not why that site ranks #1 for that query. It helps, but it's not the only or the main reason. Their incoming links using "javascript optimizer" is almost certainly the reason they rank where they do (and not coincidentally the fact that their website does just that and does it well doesn't hurt).

Answer (score 3):

The is no difference between any TLD in Google.com's search results. TLD only plays a factor in country specific searches and in those cases only country specific TLDs matter. .com, .net. info, etc, are all considered equal.